# Runtime error while trying to connect to websocket with the gorilla library

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm working with Gorilla Websocket however I get this error, it occurs after trying to visit the websocket page from localhost

Also gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when trying to visit the page

If more information is needed let me know, as its my first time posting :)

**Error**

```
2019/12/11 16:41:35 Client Connected...
2019/12/11 16:41:35 http: panic serving [::1]:37714: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 4 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc420018820)
        /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:1721 +0xd0
panic(0x65f180, 0x7e3280)
        /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Conn).NextReader(0x0, 0xc42008a0f0, 0xc42001a6c0, 0x28, 0x40, 0x28)
        /opt/gopkg/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket/conn.go:971 +0x26
github.com/gorilla/websocket.(*Conn).ReadMessage(0x0, 0xc4200c2680, 0x14, 0x28, 0x40, 0x7ecca0, 0x14)
        /opt/gopkg/src/github.com/gorilla/websocket/conn.go:1064 +0x2f
main.reader(0x0)
        /home/go/api/main2.go:23 +0x40
main.wsEndpoint(0x7c0ec0, 0xc4200e4000, 0xc42000a800)
        /home/go/api/main2.go:45 +0xeb
```

**Go Code**

```
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize: 1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool { return true },
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Home Page")
}

func reader(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        messageType, p, err := conn.ReadMessage()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        log.Println(string(p))

        if err := conn.WriteMessage(messageType, p); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
}

func wsEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    ws, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    log.Println("Client Connected...")

    reader(ws)

}

func setupRoutes() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", wsEndpoint)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Websocket server started")
    setupRoutes()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: what does upgrader.Upgrade() do?

Comment: "The Upgrader.Upgrade method upgrades the HTTP server connection to the WebSocket protocol as described in the WebSocket RFC. A summary of the process is this: The client sends an HTTP request requesting that the server upgrade the connection used for the HTTP request to the WebSocket protocol. The server inspects the request and if all is good the server sends an HTTP response agreeing to upgrade the connection. From that point on, the client and server use the WebSocket protocol over the network connection."

Comment: is there more error output? Are you sure you're calling this endpoint with a websocket connection?

Comment: Full Error: https://hastebin.com/bidegadaze.coffeescript (To long to comment)

Index.html: https://hastebin.com/uholerigep.coffeescript

Main.go: https://hastebin.com/gopakolofu.cpp

Comment: ...if you don't call the endpoint with a websocket the Upgrade() will return an error and the ws will be nil. You then use ws in the reader, which will fail because it's nil

Comment: the error you posted describes it exactly "websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header" the nil pointer is just the result of using the ws variable which is nil

Comment: I was just visiting the page normally from GET, shouldn't it open a websocket after opening the page or am I mistaken

Comment: you should try the example client/server from gorilla, I don't know too much about websockets though https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/echo

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks!